# Lua luac.exe create binary file from string

Tags: lua

Using luac5.1.exe is there anyway to pass it a string to create a binary file or does anyone know of any module that could create a syntax checked binary file, what I'm looking to do is create a settings file that can be loaded again by require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
function compile(source,file)
   io.open(file,"wb")
     :write(string.dump(assert(loadstring(source,""))))
     :close()
end
```

Comment: Why full source text is also included into output file?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I've edited the code to remove the full source.

Comment: thanks for that but I get an error running it, test string is "test test test" error is [string ""]:1:"=" expected near "<eof>" and Im unsure what that means

Comment: @Col_Blimp - `source` should be valid chunk (i.e., function's body)

Comment: @Col_Blimp, if you need better error handling, remove the assert and handle the return code from `loadstring`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `require` loads lua source files or dynamic libraries. Yu might be better off with a custom loader if you really need binary data.

Two libraries that do this are Roberto's [struct](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/) and lhf's [lpack](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lpack).

If you really want `require` then you could convert your binary data to strings, but since presumably that are `userdata`, you'll need a C function to translate the `userdata` to a Lua accessible type such as `string` or `number`.